# What does it mean when the Java console prints "Marker : e1 1234"?

Tags: java, swt, lwjgl

So I am working on a Java application using LWJGL. I am using a class for logging which will prepend messages with a timestamp and the level of the message, as seen on the first line below. However *sometimes* when I run the application, the console will print a few or many lines that start on an empty line with "Marker".

```
(2018/04/02 17:35:39)   [INFO]      Shutting down...
Marker : e1  3121
Marker : ed  5146
Marker : e1  3993
Marker : e2  3158
Marker : ee  12
```

I am not printing these myself, and so I wonder what it is. My gut tells me it's memory related, possibly given from LWJGL? Or could it be given from SWT as I'm also using that library? There's 1 more library I use (slick-util) though I don't think that's related.

It doesn't only happen after shutting down either. Sometimes it'll occur while it's running, but it's not consistent and I haven't found any patterns, and most runs it never happens at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That log should come from LWJGL, indeed the class org.lwjgl.opengl.KHRDebug  allows the GL to notify applications when various events occur that may be useful during application development, debugging and profiling.

It also defines debug markers, a mechanism for the OpenGL application to annotate the command stream with markers for discrete events.

http://www.cs.unh.edu/~cs770/lwjgl-javadoc/lwjgl-opengl/org/lwjgl/opengl/KHRDebug.html